# $\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-\sin^2(x) - A\sin^2(nx)}dx$ for an integer n

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, bessel-functions

I'm wondering how to integrate expressions of the following type:

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-\sin^2(x) - A\sin^2(nx)}dx$$

For an integer $n\neq 1$. I've tried looking at it every way I know how, I was wondering whether anyone has any clever insight? If there was a way to express this in Bessel functions that would also be great.

(I include the Bessel function tag because if A = 0 this integral can be related to a Bessel function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I present is not a closed expression but might be interesting nonetheless: we first of all can notice that it's possible to rewrite the expression $\sin^2(x) + A\sin^2(nx)$ as $$\frac{1+A}{2}-\frac{\cos(2x)+A\cos(2nx)}{2}.$$ Thus we have for the integral in question:
\begin{align*}
    \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-\sin^2(x) - A\sin^2(nx)}\,d{x}&=\int_{-\pi}^\pi\exp\left(-\frac{1+A}{2}+\frac{\cos(2x)+A\cos(2nx)}{2}\right)\,d{x}\\&=\exp\left(-\frac{1+A}{2}\right)\int_{-\pi}^\pi\exp\left(\frac{\cos(2x)+A\cos(2nx)}{2}\right)\,d{x}.
\end{align*}
After a change of variable $2x\to\theta$ and use of symmetry, this becomes:
\begin{align*}
    &\frac{1}{2}\exp\left(-\frac{1+A}{2}\right)\int_{-2\pi}^{2\pi}\exp\left(\frac{\cos(\theta)+A\cos(n\theta)}{2}\right)\,d{\theta}\\&=\exp\left(-\frac{1+A}{2}\right)\int_{0}^{2\pi}\exp\left(\frac{A}{2}\cos(n\theta)+\frac{1}{2}\cos(\theta)\right)\,d{\theta}.
\end{align*}
There exists a special relation for integrals like this using modified Bessel functions, namely
$$
    \frac{1}{2\pi }\int_0^{2\pi} \exp\bigl(z \cos (n\theta) + y \cos(\theta)\big) \,d{\theta} = I_0(z)I_0(y) + 2\sum_{m=1}^\infty I_m(z)I_{mn}(y),
$$
which after comparing the coefficients yields as final answer:
$$2\pi\exp\left(-\frac{1+A}{2}\right)\left[ I_0\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)I_0\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) + 2\sum_{m=1}^\infty I_m\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)I_{mn}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right].$$
As the modified Bessel $I_n(x)$ function goes quickly to zero for fixed $x$ and $n\to\infty$, your integral is quite well approximated with
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-\sin^2(x) - A\sin^2(nx)}\,d{x}\approx2\pi\exp\left(-\frac{1+A}{2}\right)I_0\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)I_0\left(\frac{1}{2}\right).$$

Comment: This is actually super helpful, exactly what I was looking for, thank you!
I'm not sure whether I should ask another question rather than comment this, but, how did you know this special integral relation?! Is there a resource I can refer to with all this sort of thing, or a handy way to derive these relations?
I have quite a few similar integrals (e.g. rational rather than integer n, or sums of more than two weighted combinations of $\sin^2(nx)$ at different frequencies), so I would love to learn something generalisable

Comment: Hey, glad I could help. So usually I just look in Wikipedia for help, this combined with a certain "feeling" what functions or special integrals could be involved, helps a great deal in finding relations that help. The particiular relation I used can be found on Wikipedia as well on the page on Bessel Functions, but it also can be derived using the generating function $$e^{\frac{x}{2}\bigl(t+\frac{1}{t}\big)}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}t^nI_n(x),$$ from there you find $e^{x\cos(y)}= I_0(y)+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty I_n(x) \cos(ny)$. Multiply this with itself and use orthogonality of cosines on $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: but to be sure, check the signs or factors again. The result as a whole should be correct, though.

Comment: Perfect, thanks again, I think this might have cracked a problem for me! (well, I say that now, wait until I bump into another integral I can't do...)